# Custom view/action/controller not working in Sails JS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see... Basically if I create a controller/model through `sails generate controller products` and in the file `/controllers/ProductsController` I add some variables to the index action such as:

```
index: function(req, res) {

    return res.view({
        myOne: 'World?',
        myvar: 'hello???',
        title: 'Yeap'
    })

},
```

and when I check localhost:1337/products surely enough the variables are printed within the template. Note that I haven't added a custom view and my template file is located at `views/products/index.jade` (I'm using Jade rather than EJS). However if I create a custom view in `/config/routes` such as:

```
'/custom': {

    view: 'custom',
    controller: 'ProductsController',
    action: 'customAction'

}
```

and in my ProductsController I have a very similar action as previously described:

```
customAction: function(req, res) {

    return res.view({
        myOne: 'Hello?',
        myvar: 'World???',
        title: 'Yeap'
    })

},
```

The variables are not printed in my template. The template is being called alright so is the Controller and Action (so it seems). Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Where are did you place your view -- custom.jade?

Comment: I've added in the views folder. Not under any directory. However if the error was that the view was not being found, the error would be different. The view was rendered all right, but no data was being passed through.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a choice between naming the view the same name as your action `customAction.jade` if you want to access it via:

```
index: function(req, res) {

  return res.view({
    myOne: 'World?',
    myvar: 'hello???',
    title: 'Yeap'
  })

},
```

or you can access the same view/template (e.g. index.jade) by using this syntax:

```
customAction: function(req, res) {

  return res.view('products/index', {
    myOne: 'World?',
    myvar: 'hello???',
    title: 'Yeap'
  })

},
```

I have a working repo using ejs [here](https://github.com/irlnathan/sails_custom_action_view).

Comment: How I can get them to my client side javascript. Currently I am putting them on a hidden div tag and pulling them using jquery. Is there any smarter way?

Comment: @VampireCoder it depends how you want to use it. You might just get it in the your template engine (if you the object is a list of posts you can loop through it in the template). However if you want intend to use it within your client side js, unfortunately you're stuck with either using jQuery to get it as you mentioned or making an ajax call (but that's changing quite a bit.)