# SailsJS Not Passing Data To View Template

Tags: javascript, mysql, templates, sails.js

I have been at this for hours, and just can not seem to make the connection.

I am simply just trying to pass some data from a controller to a view template.  If I run the route without a view template declared, then the browser returns the data in JSON form to the browser (so I know the MYSQL connection is good).

Whenever I try to connect to the MYSLQ data (or ANY data from the controller to view) to pass to the template, I get an error in Sails that says that the data can not be found (which I know is not true because I can see it when I just return the JSON data).  I am assuming this has to do with the way that SailsJS tries to connect to the EJS template engine, or there is something not connecting between the Model, Controller and then View on the backend?

Here is just a simple example that does not work, but in the end I am trying to connect to a MYSQL list of data.

Routes.js declaration:

```
'GET /schools': { view: 'schools/index', controller: "SchoolsController", action:"index"},
```

SchoolsController.js

```
module.exports = {
 index: function(req, res){
    //Just return this to the view
    res.view({
        "name": "Iparra"
    })
 }
};
```

index.ejs template

```
<div id="theschools">
 <h1>List of Schools</h1>
  <%= name %>
</div>
```

Error I get from Sails.js

```
{
    "stack": "ReferenceError: /Users/mnelson/Documents/Mike Files 2/Personal/MyDesign Musings/sails/test-project/views/schools/index.ejs:7\n    5|       <h1>List of Schools</h1>\n    6| \n >> 7|     <%= name %>\n    8| \n    9| </div>\n    10| \n\nname is not defined\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:109)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:237:14), <anonymous>:30:137)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:250:15\n    at Object.exports.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:288:13)\n    at Object.exports.renderFile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:318:20)\n    at SailsView.module.exports [as engine] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/ejs-locals/index.js:85:7)\n    at SailsView.View.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/view.js:76:8)\n    at Function.app.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/application.js:561:10)\n    at ServerResponse.res.render (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/response.js:845:7)\n    at ServerResponse.res.view (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/res.view.js:284:16)\n    at serveView (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/onRoute.js:61:20)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)\n    at nextRoute (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:100:7)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:167:11)\n    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/cors/clear-headers.js:14:3)\n    at routeTargetFnWrapper (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/lib/router/bind.js:181:5)\n    at callbacks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)\n    at param (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)\n    at pass (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/sails/node_modules/@sailshq/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)",
  "message": "/Users/mnelson/Documents/Mike Files 2/Personal/My Design Musings/sails/test-project/views/schools/index.ejs:7\n    5|       <h1>List of Schools</h1>\n    6| \n >> 7|     <%= name %>\n    8| \n    9| </div>\n    10| \n\nname is not defined",
  "path": "/Users/mnelson/Documents/Mike Files 2/Personal/My Design Musings/sails/test-project/views/schools/index.ejs"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While digging through the docs and looking at other Github examples, I finally sorted it through. Sujan got me on the right path, but that did not solve the problem.  It would return the data, but it was not then coupled with the view.  Here is what I updated to and this now pulls the whole list of data in.  I had to explicitly ret to the view with the data.  I'm not sure if that's the way it's supposed to be within Sails, but that is what made it work.  It seems like the route should handle this, but it doesn't.

Controller File:

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
      Schools.find().exec(function afterFind(err, schools) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        console.log(schools);
        return res.view('schools/index', {
          theschools: schools
        });
      });
    }
};
```

Route File:

```
'GET /schools': {controller: 'SchoolsController', action:'index'},
```

Also, I needed to update the blueprints.js file in config to remove the limit on the find method.

```
defaultLimit: Number.MAX_VALUE
```

I also updated the template engine to pug.  Here is the view file, index.pug

```
extends ../layout

block body
  #theschools
    h1
    |  List of Schools
  p
  table.table
    tr
      th ID
      th Name
      th City
      th Country
    each school in theschools
      tr
        td= school.SID
        td= school.schoolName
        td= school.schoolCity
        td= school.schoolCountry
```

Looking at the answer to this Stackoverflow question and answer helped me to remove the explicit view declaration in the controller.
[Custom view/action/controller not working in Sails JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882748/custom-view-action-controller-not-working-in-sails-js?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your routes. Remove `view: 'schools/index'` from

```
'GET /schools': { view: 'schools/index', controller: "SchoolsController", action:"index"},
```

Or just change it to

```
'GET /schools': { 'SchoolsController.index' },
```

**Why?**

In routes you have to specify either which controller action to execute or which view to render(if its a static page)

`res.view` takes an optional first argument as view path(relative to `views/`) and if its not sent, it will render `<contollerName>/<actionName>` view by default.

Comment: Thank you for this!  It didn't solve the problem, but it got me on the right path of sorting through how the data, view, and route was connected.   Appreciate it!